# How to find out where our store has been updated

Tags: react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I want to keep the states in asyncstorage when our store is updated...
I used redux , and I'm going to keep all the states in asyncstorage
I don't know exactly where to do this.
Help me please
thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several AsyncStore's method can help you store value like dictionary.

- `AsyncStore.setItem(key, value)` to store
- `AsyncStore.getItem(key)` to get value of key
- `AsyncStore.clear()` to clear storage

Remember those method always return as a Promise.

But I recommend you use `redux-persist` to keep your state since you use redux. It help you in the more convenient way